# Search for table name used in multiple stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I just joined a team that's about to do some extensive modifications in our data-warehouse fact tables.

I have been assigned to modify all the procedures and functions that use them.

When I run the following query

```
SELECT  * FROM mysql.proc
```

I get a list of the functions, procedures , in/out parameters that exist. But it doesn't show me what table(s) is/are in use in each function or procedure.

Several challenges:

1. naming convention is non existing so guessing is time-consuming
2. code that's out there is not in Git.

We have over 300 procedures and functions.

If all the code was in a file on my server, I would simply grep it for my table names. Is there a way to show what table(s) is/are in use in each function or procedure?.

Comment: is it executed at MySQL or in code (as in php)?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs MySQL. Shell script calls the stored procedure.

Comment: Might be better to do a `grep` on the files to see what tables it runs the procedures on

Comment: select routine_definition  from information_schema.routines will give you the code for procedures and functions.

Comment: @P.Salmon Life-saver. This newbie thanks you.